# Python equal operator, avoid bugs of type: (<string> == <number>) -> False

Tags: python, design-patterns, operators, duck-typing

Is there a way to obtain an exception when the == (equal) operator is used to compare different types? Python 3 throws an exception when attempting to order objects of different types. But  ==  still returns False.

Or is there some other way to avoid hard to detect bugs caused by wrong type assumptions? Are there any design-patterns that could help?

I'm thinking of, e.g., a case where someone uses someone elses implementation of xmlparser.get() which always returns a string, even if the property is basically a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because for ==, the reasoning is that equality implies comparibility. If two objects aren't even comparable they are not equal, therefore it will return false and never throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

No, python is inherently dynamically typed.

If you *must* doublecheck a type, use the [`isinstance()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance), or use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) to test for specific behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking of, e.g., a case where someone uses someone elses implementation of xmlparser.get() which always returns a string, even if the property is basically a number.

You might want to coerce the value to a number by calling `int` or `float` on it, as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that Python has dynamic typing, it is **strong** (not duck). So:

```
>>> 42 == 42
True
>>> 42 == 42.0
True
>>> 42 == "42"
False
>>> 42 == int("42")
True
```

You have to perform an explicit type conversion when getting a string representation of the number.

On the other hand, you can manage comparison of your custom objects by defining methods [`__eq__(self, other)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) or [`__cmp__(self, other)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) in your class.